# Function returning a value

Tags: c++

I am doing a course on data structure and algorithm. There is this code written here where there is a function `mf()`. It returns `int old`.My question is that how can it return `old` since `int old` is a local variable which will be destroyed at the time of return.

```
class x{
public;
int m;
int mf(int v){int old = m; m = v; return old; }
};
```

Comment: C++ copies values by default, it doesn't pass around references unless you do so explicitly. The value of `old` will be copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns the value of `old`, not the variable itself. It is returning a copy of the value.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's getting late and I'm answering on my phone. I started getting pointers suck on my head, so i just ripped all of that out and went with the simpler version.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ will pass the value of the return variable to a temporary value:

```
class x{
    public:
    int m;
    int mf(int v){
        int old = m; // store member var m in old.
        m = v; // change m to v.
        return old; // return the old value of m.
                    // **tmp = old;**
    }
};

x foo;
foo.m = 5;
int n = foo.mf(3); // n = tmp; so now tmp is 5, and it's assigned to n;
```

You can observe the copy from `old` to `tmp` and destory of `old` and `tmp` when you return a class and print a message in the constructor and destructor.

FYI, the compiler can use [return value optimization (RVO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) to store the return value directly in `n`.